# Semantic loans; words borrowing a meaning already there?

Tags: etymology, semantics, morphology, linguistic-typology, cross-linguistic

**What exactly is a semantic loan, how can a word borrow a meaning it already has?**

I am trying to figure out whether there are any limitations (can we choose any morphemes) on the recipient word and the meaning it already has (whether a word can borrow a meaning it already has).

An *example* is the Greek word αντίληψη[image]

A complex process through which humans acquire knowledge about reality, either directly through the senses or indirectly through the intervention of reason.

Lidel Scott says the word already meant that since classical times.
Grasping with the mind, apprehension, perception, comprehension, Epicur.Fr.250, Stoic.2.206, Diog.Oen.4; φυσικὴν ἀντίληψιν ποιεῖσθαί τινος D.S.3.15; οὐκ ἐπιστρέφει τὴν ἀντίληψιν does not attract the attention, [Longin.] Rh.p.190H.; of sensuous perception, Stoic.2.230, Ti.Locr. 100b, Anon.in Tht.59.48, Phld.Herc.1003, Alex Aphr.in Top.91.5; ποιοτήτων Plu.2.625b, cf. Metrod.1.

[image]

I am thinking that per (thoroughly) should be translated as παρa (or at least κατα) and capio should be translated as κτω. Usucapio χρηστικτησία. There is the issue of the voice too. Capio is active Capior is passive

Παρακτώ or Κατακτώ (which actually is an existing word meaning Conquer, Seize).

Comment: I’m not sure I get quite what you’re asking here. A semantic loan is when the meaning of an existing word is extended to include an additional meaning an equivalent word in another language has. As I understand it, αντίληψη ‘perception’ already meant ‘how something is understood’, but was extended to include the broader sense ‘ability to perceive through the senses’ (and some other senses) based on French use. [As an aside, why should _capio_ ‘grasp, seize, get’ be translated with κτάομαι ‘get, obtain’, rather than λαμβάνω ‘grasp, seize, take’?]

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I don't understand the difference between the supposed 2 meanings (The Classical one and the Borrowed one). They seem to be the same to me. One is just a more comprehensive definition of the same meaning (as I understand it). As I understand it is λαμβάνω that means get, obtain and κτω (active) mean seize, conquer. Καταλαμβάνω, κατάληψη is Squatting, Seizing while Κατακτώ means to conquer (it seems to be much more forceful).

Comment: The difference is concrete vs abstract, I’d say. The existing sense is basically equivalent to ‘understanding’ (i.e., the act or an instance of perceiving/understanding something). The borrowed sense is more about the abstract human ability to use our senses to perceive and make sense of the world around it – a term one might use when discussing philosophy or psychology.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet So it's not just 2 definitions for the same thing (same meaning)?Could we formulate this into an answer for **What exactly is a semantic loan, how can a word borrow a meaning it already has?** The question was about semantic loans in their generality across any languages.

Comment: A good example of a semantic loan is the Malay/Indonesian word _buah_ “a fruit, like a banana or a pineapple” which acquired another meaning “result” by semantic loan from Sanskrit where the noun फल (phala) means _both_ “fruit” _and_ “result, yield, consequence”. Here we have exactly the same thing as with your Greek word, the original meaning was concrete, but the 2nd, abstract, meaning was borrowed from a language where the corresponding word had both meanings, concrete and abstract, as @JanusBahsJacquet reasonably points out.

Comment: @YellowSky The difference between a botanical fruit and the result, the yield of something is clear. If anything a botanical fruit is the crop the yield of a plant (a special case of "fruit"). But I don't understand the difference between what LSJ says was meant in Epicur.Fr.250, Stoic.2.206, Diog.Oen.4; and what Triantafyllides means. I think they mean the same thing and Triantafyllides has embelished his definition more, it is more comprehensive it is better.

Comment: So is your question about why that very dictionary wrote that and that or about what a semantic loan is? I don't know Greek enough as to understand your first screenshot, neither did I read those Greek authors so as to be able to check whether the reference in your second screenshot is true and they really used that word in that meaning. If you could provide a good English translation of your 1st screenshot and of the passages quoted in your 2nd one, then we can consider your claims, but without anything like that our talk is about nothing.

Comment: I want to be clear: my understanding of the claim in your 1st picture is that the meaning “sensual perception, perception with our sense organs like eyes, ears, nose, etc.” was the semantical loan, while originally it meant only “perception as grasping with the mind = understanding”. Apart from the question of which one is more concrete and which one is more abstract here, it can be the case that some of the Greek philosophers quoted used that word in that meaning as their own occasionalism, but using it as a term for sense perception was firmly established under the French influence.

Comment: @YellowSky The important part is 1a (Psychology) A complex process through which humans acquire knowledge about reality, either directly through the senses or indirectly through the intervention of reason (I already gave a translation in my question). below it explains the origins. 1a: & Semantical Loan French Perception. I haven't read myself the passages quoted in LSJ. And then I am buffled By the definition in 1b the ability of a person to understand. Maybe it meant 1b and 1a was the acquired-borrowed meaning but I don't understand the difference.

Comment: It's semantic, in general. This term is more than one thing in Greek, is it not?